# Clear or Destroy Kendo Tooltip

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, tooltip, kendo-tooltip

I am unable to clear kendo tooltip.
My code is as follows:

```
var tooltip = $("#DIV_ID").kendoTooltip();
tooltip.hide();
```

I also tried destroy event but tooltip is not getting cleared properly.

[image: I have added an image for how tooltip appears after clearing it.]

Answer (score 6):

In order to invoke the method `hide` of `kendoTooltip` you should do:

```
tooltip.data("kendoTooltip").hide();
```

What you do with `tooltip.hide();` is hiding the HTML element associated to the tooltip.

In order to destroy the tooltip, you should do:

```
tooltip.data("kendoTooltip").destroy();
```

Check the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/f5g7C/

1. when clicking on <kbd>Hide tooltip</kbd> you hide the tooltip (but it will show again when the mouse is over)
2. when clicking on <kbd>Hide DIV</kbd> you hide the `DIV` associated to the tooltip
3. when clicking on <kbd>Destroy tooltip</kbd> you `destroy` the tooltip